# Java Swing HiDPI Scaling

Tags: java, swing, hidpi

I have created a program using Java 8 that utilises a Swing GUI in the Eclipse IDE. To scale images and icons to appropriate sizes, it gets and uses the screen resolution. Upon compiling the program within Eclipse, the program displays perfectly fine, and everything seems to operate as it should. However, when I export the project as a "Runnable Jar", and run the program, the image scaling and the program look and feel are all off.

Upon further investigation, it appears that the runnable jar was returning a screen resolution that is exactly 2.5x less then that in eclipse (which is the actual resolution - 3840x2160 vs 1536x864). There is circumstantial evidence across the internet that Java 8 Look and Feels (or something of the sort) don't support HiDPI screen scaling. There are scattered solutions that claim to fix the problem, like updating to Java versions past 8, or by adding arguments to the jar compilation (whatever that means). This is already confusing to a Java novice, and it is only made more confusing by the program being displayed perfectly when run/compiled within the Eclipse IDE.

My question is whether anyone knows how to get a program compiled in Java using Swing to scale correctly on an HiDPI screen, and what the process is that I need to follow to compile a working program?

EDIT 1: Something interesting to note is that in my Windows settings, the "Scale and Layout", "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" is set to exactly 250%, meaning that this setting is obviously the cause of the scaling issues I am encountering. Does someone know how to bypass this setting from within the program, or why it works when I run it through Eclipse?

Comment: What are the parameters used by eclipse in the launch configuration?

Comment: In my experience, the first Java version that properly handles HiDPI screens is Java 12. Try running (no need to _compile_) your application with Java 12 and see if that improves things.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Eclipse isn't using any parameters (arguments?) when it runs the program @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For some reason deleting all other versions of java off my system and instead using Java 12 worked, slightly. Suddenly the resolution of the text on the screen started scaling correctly to the right size, but the incorrect screen resolution problem still remains.

Comment: What is the _Run Configuration_ in _Eclipse_ for launching your program? From the _Eclipse_ menu choose _Run_ > _Run Configurations..._

Comment: If you scale the HiDPI display, you get a smaller effective resolution - that is to be expected I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 8 does not support High DPI. On Windows, it runs in DPI unaware mode and relies on Windows to stretch the window bitmap to the scale set for the monitor in the settings. It means the UI of the application looks blurry when displayed on a High DPI monitor.

Later versions of Java, Java 11 and above, support per-monitor High DPI settings. The UI of your application is correctly scaled up according to the settings, the text remains crisp. For the icons and images to remain crisp, you should use [`MultiResolutionImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/MultiResolutionImage.html) or its basic implementation [`BaseMultiResolutionImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BaseMultiResolutionImage.html) to provide higher resolution alternatives.

You should not base your images based on the screen resolution but rather on the scale set for a monitor. For example, a Full HD monitor 1920×1080 with 150% scale has the effective resolution 1280×720, it is the effective resolution that Java reports to you.